# Hodge structure of the cohomology of a complement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is the hodge structure given to the cohomology of the complement of a closed subset with respect to a smooth variety?

This is *not* quite  what is wanted. In fact,
The hodge structure is constructed as in Deligne's Hodge theory II where it is shown that it does not depend on the compactification  but  the question is: can we compare the Hodge structure of $ H^i(U, C) $ and  $ H^i_c( U,C) $ asumming that $ U = X -Y $ where $ X$ is a smooth, compact  ( say $P^4$) and $ Y $  is a hypersurface  which admits only isolated double points?

What we can actually  construct is the Gauss-Mannin connection on $Gr_F ^3 H^4(U,C)$ but we would like to relate it to the given by taking cohomology with compact supports on  $ H^4_c( U,C) $. Of course, you can always think of an exact sequence involving $ H^i( X,C) $ and  $ H^i_c( U, C) $ but remember $X$ *is singular*.

Comment: Well it's a mixed Hodge structure in general. As to how you construct it, take a look at the book by Peters and Steenbrink on MHS, or the original paper of Deligne Theorie de Hodge II,

Comment: $H^{i}_c(U,\mathbb{C})$ is *dual* to $H^{2n-i}(U,\mathbb{C})$ (as mixed Hodge structures), with $n=\dim U$. Apparently you are considering the case $i=n=4$ so this should answer your question.

Comment: You mean exactly the mapping given by